# Use Poco::Crypto::DigestEngine in Poco::HMACEngine

Tags: poco-libraries

Poco supports `HMACEngine` with different hash functions. For example to create a HMAC-SHA1 function I can use `HMACEngine<SHA1Engine> hmca_sha1("secret");`

This works well with `DigestEngine` like `SHA1Engine` and `MD5Engine` that have a constructor without argument.

Is it possible to use `HMACEngine` with hash functions from OpenSSL as they are provided by `Poco::Crypto::DigestEngine`?

The problem is that these functions take a string parameter in their constructor that specifies which hashing algorithm to use. This means `HMACEngine<Poco::Crypto:DigestEngine> hmca_xxx("secret");` wouldn't work.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will require some coding on Poco side. HMAC is accepting any class as template argument, and hoping it is a `Digest` class ans using methods like digest() that may not even exist. The HMACEngine that instantiates the class as template, so you can´t passa anything to its constructor as it is. In fact I don´t think that is a good use of templates, while I´m not very familiar with using this C++ resource yet, I think one should not expect anything to be available from templated class.

Probably a new `HMACEngine` for the `Crypto` module (instead of `Foundation` module) would be good. But looks like an approach more like the `Poco::Crypto::RSADigestEngine` would be better than the current template based one. I´ve recently modified `Poco::Crypto::RSADigestEngine` to be based on `Poco::Crypto::DigestEngine` instead off old Foundation `Poco::DigestEngine`, and therefore for next release it will also support all hashes that OpenSSL support. Basically `RSADigestEngine` creates an instance of a `Poco::Crypto::DigestEngine` as base and uses it.

I could help on a patch proposal if you create one at github. Poco::Crypto does need some updates :)

Comment: One solution I was thinking about was to create wrapper classes in `Poco::Crypto`. I mean a class like `Poco::Crypto::SHA256DigestWrapper` that internaly creates the required OpenSSL hash engine using `Poco::Crypto::DigestEngine`.
This is basically what I am doing right now in my code.